Calibrating the headphone for proper (subjective) hearing volume
How to set the volume of a headphone so that the volume heard while doing audio work will be consistent for listening audience?
I suppose there's a particular waveform that should be played for a human to hear, and he/she will set the volume of the headphone to a subjectively comfortable level before doing the audio work. Is there such standard?

There is no particular waveform to hear. As everyone is different and has their own preferences, you should listen to tracks you are familiar with so you can gauge the volume that works for you.
